# Test a function with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

How can I test a function like the one below using jest?

```
lightboxUrl: function () {
    var componentId = this.options.componentId
    if (componentId) {
      var album = this.model.get('album')

      var shortcut = this.model.get('shortcut')
      return '/lightbox/' + componentId + '/' + album + '/' + shortcut
    }
  }
```

New to javascript Testing. Any help greatly appreciated.Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just assumed and stubbed some of the not provided details.

Here is the lightbox item

```
export default function lightboxParent(componentId) {
 return {
  options: {
   componentId,
  },
  model: {
   get: id => (id === "album" ? "album" : "shortcut"),
  },
  lightboxUrl: function() {
   var componentId = this.options.componentId;
   if (componentId) {
    var album = this.model.get("album");

    var shortcut = this.model.get("shortcut");
    return "/lightbox/" + componentId + "/" + album + "/" + shortcut;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Here is the jest test

```
describe("lightbox url", () => {
  it("should be valid url", () => {
    expect(lightboxParent(1).lightboxUrl()).toBe(
      "/lightbox/1/album/shortcut"
    );
  });
  it("should not resolve valid url, no componentId", () => {
    expect(lightboxParent().lightboxUrl()).toBe(undefined);
  });
});
```

i used codesandbox for this, https://codesandbox.io/s/n4mlqkr4qj

This is a basic test just checking the url that the `lightboxUrl` method is returning or if no componentId, that it's `undefined`, as the entire src was provided and i made a few assumptions i just left it basic